# array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to lambda expression and little confused why I'm getting the error here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 11, 21, 4, 13 };

    for_each(arr, arr + 4, [arr](int x) {
        cout << x;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I just add LAMBDA for this function.

```
void fun1(int x)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
```

Here is the error message on visual studio.

```
'main::<lambda_4ee0815d3a456ed46cc70a2a94c10f76>::arr': 
array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list Project1
```

Comment: Ey, yet another problem caused by the use of C arrays! Seriously, just use `std::array` already if you have C++11.

Comment: Is `arr`needed at all? Doesn't `[](int x) {...` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot copy arrays, so you can capture `arr` by reference instead if you actually need it:

```
for_each(arr, arr + 4, [&arr](int x) { cout << x; });
//                     ^^^
```

However, since you don't refer to the array in the lambda body, you don't need to capture it at all:

```
for_each(arr, arr + 4, [](int x) { cout << x; });
//                    ^^^^
```

Comment: Kerrek SB, why? can you explain please? if I want to capture array then?

Comment: @UnKnown: Good point, you don't need the array at all. *You* tell *me* why you want to capture it!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: No, why? Are you thinking of `[p = arr]`? That's different from `[arr]`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: It's the same error as if you had `struct X { int a_[4]; X(int (&a)[4]) : a_(a) {} };`.